# How to join these two tables (creating multilanguage interface)

Tags: mysql

I have a problem with joining tables, here is the situation:

Table 1 (countries): id, name

Table 2 (countries_lng): id, orig_id, name, lng_id

orig_id is a foreign key of countries.id

What I need is to create a sql query that will show the rows from countries and assign them ID 1 and from the countries_lng it will show the correct lng_id from table.

Is it possible somehow?

Right now I can't move all the data from tables to their respective _lng table so I'm looking for this temporary solution.

Thanks in advance.

// Edit

Example of how it looks like now and how do I want it to look like:

countries:
id: 1, name: Česká republika

countries_lng:
id: 1, orig_id: 1, name: Czech republic, lng_id: 2

Result:

id: 1, name: Česká republika, lng_id: 1

id: 1, name: Czech republic, lng_id: 2

Comment: To whoever downvoted this: If you downvote something, it would be fair to write why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use UNION for joining results.

For example:

```
select id, name
from countries
where id_lang=1
union
select id, name
from countries_lang
where id_lang=1
```

Result:

```
id  name
1   Česká republika
1   Czech republic
```

If you need the column lng_id then you must this column add to the countries table (with any default value):

```
select id, name, lng_id
from countries
-- where lng_id=1
union
select id, name, lng_id
from countries_lang
-- where lng_id=1
```

or simulate this column in countries:

```
select id, name, 1 as lng_id
from countries
union
select id, name, lng_id
from countries_lang
```

result:

```
id  name    lng_id
1   Česká republika 1
1   Czech republic  2
```